# Calculate area of specific color in a image (Inter-Metallic Coverage (IMC)) - Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm planning to create an app to measure an area of specific color in an image.
Specifically, this app tend to measure the **Inter-Metallic Coverage (IMC).**
This IMC measurement is a process in determining the area of a ball bond which has intermetallic growth - this is commonly performed in semicon industry, specifically in wirebond assembly process.

I'm self learning python for a while and already created several simple apps using tkinter, pandas, selenium and other basic libraries to automate several task at work.

I already googled around but I cannot find the app I needed so I decided to create my own app if ever.
Please help me where to start, what module I should learn?

Initially, the app should function like these:

1. Create lasso tool (just like in photoshop) to select the region of interest(ROI), this will be the total area.
2. Then another selector to select the gold color inside the ROI - Maybe just like the magic wand tool of photoshop. Or maybe, a color picker tool.
3. Then, I will subtract the area of the gold color from the total (ROI), that will be the IMC.

[image]
[image]

Is it possible that I can create the app using python?

Thank you so much as always.

Comment: possible? sure. you "just" need to know some image processing. you wanna learn about binarization/masks, about `cv.cvtColor` and `cv.inRange`

Comment: Thank you @ChristophRackwitz. So basically, what I needed to learn OpenCV.